# cascade dropdown to autocomplete textbox using jquery in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, filter, cascade

I'm intend to cascade the dropdownlist to textbox, so if I choose the dropdown list, the autocomplete list will only shown the data that included in the selected dropdown.

but I get confused in the jquery

here is my jquery

```
            $('#<%=searchTxt.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    var d = { modelName: request.term, 
                    merkId: $("#ddlMerk").val()};

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "default2.asmx/GetModelName",
                        data : JSON.stringify(d),
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log(data.d)
                            response(data.d.slice(0, 10));
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                            console.log("err res->>", result);
                        }
                    });
                },
            minLength: 3
            });
        });
```

and I stuck there, I don't know how to collide the value of dropdown to autocomplete textbox.

it's my aspx.cs to get value to dropdown

private void BindGrid()
{ DataSet dataset= get_merk();

```
        if (dataset != null)
        {
            ddlMerk.DataTextField = "MERK_NAME";
            ddlMerk.DataValueField = "MERK_ID";
            ddlMerk.DataSource = dataset;
            ddlMerk.DataBind();
        }

    }

    public DataSet get_merk()
    {
        
        OracleConnection conn = null;
        OracleCommand comm = null;
        OracleDataAdapter adapter = null;
        DataSet dataset = null;
        string sError = "";

        try
         {
            conn = new OracleConnection(CUtility.ConnectionString);
            comm = new OracleCommand("Package_AUTOCOMPLETE.get_merk", conn);
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; comm.BindByName = true;
            adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(comm);
            dataset = new DataSet("get_merk");

            comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_CURSOR", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_STATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_ERROR_MESSAGE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            adapter.Fill(dataset);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
            dataset = null;
            sError = ex.Message; sError = sError.Replace("'", "");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
                conn.Close();
            conn = null;

            if (comm != null)
                comm.Dispose();

            if (adapter != null)
                adapter.Dispose();
        }
        if (dataset==null)
        {
            Response.Write("check dataset");Response.End();
        }

        return dataset;
                    
    }
```

and it's my asmx to get autocomplete lis

public List GetModelName(string modelName, string merkId)
{ List modelNames = new List();

```
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cs);
    {
        OracleCommand comm = new OracleCommand("Package_AUTOCOMPLETE.get_model", conn);
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_STRINGMODEL", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 80)).Value = modelName;
        comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_STRINGMERK", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 80)).Value = merkId;
        comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_CURSOR", OracleDbType.RefCursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_STATUS", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 1)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("P_ERROR_MESSAGE", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 100)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


        conn.Open();
        OracleDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            modelNames.Add(rdr["MODEL_DESC"].ToString());
        }
    }
    return modelNames;
}
```

here is my Json view

[
{
"MERK_ID": "1",
"MERK_NAME": "AUDI",
"TYPE_NAME": "A3",
"MODEL_NAME": "1.2 TFSI",
"MODEL_DESC": "AUDI-A3-1.2 TFSI"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "1",
"MERK_NAME": "AUDI",
"TYPE_NAME": "A3",
"MODEL_NAME": "NEW 2.0 FSI SPORTBACK TRIPTRONIC",
"MODEL_DESC": "AUDI-A3-NEW 2.0 FSI SPORTBACK TRIPTRONIC"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "1",
"MERK_NAME": "AUDI",
"TYPE_NAME": "A3",
"MODEL_NAME": "S3 LIMOUSINE 2.0 TFSI QUATTRO",
"MODEL_DESC": "AUDI-A3-S3 LIMOUSINE 2.0 TFSI QUATTRO"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "2",
"MERK_NAME": "BAJAJ",
"TYPE_NAME": "AVENGER",
"MODEL_NAME": "CRUISE 220",
"MODEL_DESC": "BAJAJ-AVENGER-CRUISE 220"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "2",
"MERK_NAME": "BAJAJ",
"TYPE_NAME": "AVENGER",
"MODEL_NAME": "STREET 160",
"MODEL_DESC": "BAJAJ-AVENGER-STREET 160"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "2",
"MERK_NAME": "BAJAJ",
"TYPE_NAME": "CT",
"MODEL_NAME": "100",
"MODEL_DESC": "BAJAJ-CT-100"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "3",
"MERK_NAME": "BENELLI",
"TYPE_NAME": "502C",
"MODEL_NAME": "500 CC",
"MODEL_DESC": "BENELLI-502C-500 CC"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "3",
"MERK_NAME": "BENELLI",
"TYPE_NAME": "CAFERACER",
"MODEL_NAME": "1130 CC",
"MODEL_DESC": "BENELLI-CAFERACER-1130 CC"
},
{
"MERK_ID": "3",
"MERK_NAME": "BENELLI",
"TYPE_NAME": "LEONCINO",
"MODEL_NAME": "250",
"MODEL_DESC": "BENELLI-LEONCINO-250"
},

Comment: Ok it is not very clear what you are asking.  I suggest you add a complete fully working sample of code so we can try to do what you are doing. Fully reproducible example

Comment: I already edit my question, I add some code.

Comment: and i already put my Json too